# mod_passenger options - invalid command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, redmine

I have a Ubuntu server(11.10) and use mod_passenger for Redmine. It works pretty well, but somehow slow on first run (once in a while).

I've googled and came up into this:
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerMinInstances

However I can't setup any of the specified options. They just don't work. 
I've tried in:

- apache2/sites-avalible/redmine
- apache2/mods-avalible/passenger.conf
- apache2/httpd.conf

Wherever I put a command like 'PassengerMinInstances 3' and try to reload Apache I get:

```
Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/redmine:
Invalid command 'PassengerMinInstances', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
...fail!
```

Ofcourse the lines and files differ.
Logs don't hold anything related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu ships with an older Passenger version that not yet supports the `PassengerMinInstances` option.

As an alternative you could set `PassengerPoolIdleTime` and `PassengerMaxRequests` to a rather high value to prevent idle instances to be recycled.

You could also use the Ubuntu package provided by Phusion. See http://wiki.brightbox.co.uk/docs:phusion-passenger for more information about that

Finally, you could also install the current version of Passenger using rubygems. For that remove the `libapache2-mod-passenger` package and run this:

```
sudo aptitude purge libapache2-mod-passenger
sudo apt-get install rubygems build-essential apache2-prefork-dev libapr1-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo gem install passenger
sudo /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module
```

It will compile and install passenger. At the end, it will output some configuration values that you need to put in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load`.

Then enable passenger by running

```
sudo a2enmod passenger
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and everything should be well.

Comment: Well the installation of new passenger was a littlebit diffrent in my case. I've choosen installing as a gem. I could run 'passsenger-install-apache2-module' without specifying a path (which was diffrent anyway). Also modules-avalible don't contain a folder for passenger. However - that was it. Now it works like a charm. Thank you, that made my redmine faster, and I am very happy for it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you placing it in the same file in which you are loading the Passenger module?  E.g. are you placing those lines underneath a line that looks something like the following?

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails31/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

Comment: in file: /etc/apache2/mods-avalible/passenger.load: LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so
PassengerMinInstances 3 - still doesn't work.